# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is part of my python script that is giving error:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(element_table)
xml = ET.tostring(element_table)
xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><?xml-  stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\".\/xsl\/brsdk.xsl\"?>" + xml
obis_file = open( "OBIS_Support_Chart_" + sdk_version.replace( ".","_" ) +   ".xml", "w" )
obis_file.write( xml.decode('utf8') )
```

The error flagged during running of the script is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 115, in <module>
    xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><?xml- stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\".\/xsl\/brsdk.xsl\"?>" + xml
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

What is problem there in the script? I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [ElementTree.tostring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) mentions this behavior:

> Use `encoding="unicode"` to generate a Unicode string (otherwise, a bytestring is generated).

So in your case, since you don’t specify `encoding="unicode"` when calling `tostring()`, it returns a `bytes` object. Thus, when you try to concatenate a *string* with the previous output of `tostring()`, you try to concatenate a string with bytes, hence the error.

Specify the encoding to fix this:

```
xml = ET.tostring(element_table, encoding='unicode')
```

Since you then have an actual `str` object, you also no longer need to decode `xml` when writing to the file:

```
obis_file.write(xml)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but i need to made some modification in obis_file.write(xml).